# Fourier-measurable set and fourier-measurable functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

This question arises from the book titled 'Higher order fourier analysis' by T. Tao.

Fourier complexity: A function $f:[N] \to \mathbb{C}$ has fourier complexity at most M if it can be expressed as $$f(n) =\sum_{m=1}^M'c_me(\alpha_m n)$$ for some $M' \leq M$  and some complex numbers $c_1,\cdots,c_{M'}$ of magnitude atmost $1$, and some real numbers $\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_{M'}$.

Also, if $f,g$ has fourier complexity $M$, then $f+g, f-g, \overline{f},or fg$ all have Fourier complexity atmost $O_M(1)$.

Definition: Let $\mathcal{F}: \mathbb{R}^{+} \to \mathbb{R}^{+}$ be a function. We say that a function $f:[N]\to \mathbb{C}$ is *Fourier Measurable* with growth function $\mathcal{F}$ if, for every $K>1$, one can find a function $f_k:[N]\to \mathbb{C}$ of Fourier complexity at most $\mathcal{F}(K)$ such that $\mathbb{E}_{n\in [N]}|f(n)-f_K(n)|\leq 1/K$.

A subset $A$ of $[N]$ is fourier measurable with growth function $\mathcal{F}$ if $1_A$ is fourier measurable with this growth function.

*Question*: I wish to know that how does a fourier measurable set look like? What role or significance does it have?

*Question*: Can someone please give me an example of a fourier measurable set and a fourier measurable function (except the indicator function of the set). I want to grasp the intuitive idea behind introducing such a definition and why is it so useful!

Prof Terence Tao uses this definition in a lemma which is stated below:

Lemma: (correlation with fourier character implies correlation with a fourier measurable set). Let $f:[N]\to \mathbb{C}$ be bounded in magnitude by $1$, and suppose that $|\mathbb{E}_{n\in [N]} f(n) e(-\alpha n)|\geq \delta$ for some $\delta >0$. Then there exists a **fourier-measurable set $E\subset [N]$** with growth function $\mathcal{F}$ depending on $\delta$ such that $|\mathbb{E}_{n\in [N]}f(n)1_E(n)|\gg \delta$.

Comment: Some notation is left undefined. I guess $[N]=\{1,2,\dots,N\}$ but i dont know what Fouerier complexity is. I would guess $\mathbb E_{n\in[N]}=\frac1N\sum_{n=1}^N$, and that you are missing a closing "$|$" for the norm? But I'm not sure and I don't have the book.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes, $[N]:=\{1,2,\cdots, N\}$ and the notation for $\mathbb{E}_{n\in [N]}$ is also right and thank you for the closing of norm part. I have edited it now!

Comment: Using this information, can you please try to help me out on this particular question?

Comment: i still don’t know what Fourier complexity is. And this is quite far from what I know, so no promises

Comment: A function $f:[N] \to \mathbb{C}$ has fourier complexity at most M if it can be expressed as $$f(n) =\sum_{m=1}^M'c_me(\alpha_m n)$$ for some $M' \leq M$  and some complex numbers $c_1,\cdots,c_{M'}$ of magnitude atmost $1$, and some real numbers $\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_{M'}$.